# "Windows Security" alert when moving files in My Documents/Desktop (local disk)

Tags: windows-7, security, uac, my-documents

Every time I try to move a file to a different location in My Documents or on the Desktop by dragging it I get a "Windows Security" alert telling me "These files might be harmful to your computer".

I am not trying to move files across a network or anything. I simply want to move the files from 1 folder to another in the same directory on a local disk.

I have search the internet for this problem and everything relates to files being copied across networks, not local files. The most common solution for that problem was to reset the internet security settings which I have done with no luck.

**Details:**

- I can open, edit and rename files with no problems/alerts.
- I can move files using Cut/Past with no problems/alerts.
- The problem affects all files/folders in My Documents and on my Desktop.
- The problem affects newly created files/folders as well as old files/folders.

**My Computer**

- Windows 7 Home Premium (64bit)
- I am the only user on the computer (Administrator)

Thanks.

Comment: You are getting this message if you move a file from Folder A to Folder B and both folders are located with the `Desktop` and `My Documents` profile directories?

Comment: This may help you http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/windows-security-these-files-might-be-harmful/6459a622-8780-48eb-a946-2281f3225c34

Comment: @Ramhound that is correct. Something as simple as creating a blank text document in `My Documents` and then dragging it to a sub-folder causes the alert every time.

Comment: @vembutech Thank's for the link. I tried everything suggested and some more I Googled based on the suggestions and still had no luck in fixing it.